# How to save multiple images in a file upload in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I'll try these codes, in this code file uploader takes many images, if 1st time choose 3 images and again choose 1 image, we see 4 images but save only last file i.e 1 image. Here is my code

In .aspx file

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImagePreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#imgViewer').append($('<img>', { src: e.target.result, width: '50px', height: '50' }));

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: show your server side code and html code for calling upload

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
        { HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            { hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("TestingImages") + "\\" +
                System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " + hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");
            } } }

Comment: this code works fine ...  example: I choose 3 images together and after that, I upload 1 image more that means 4 images save but last one image save only. In .aspx.cs code fines ,  when i choose one image that 3 files instead change last file name

Comment: please post it in question, not in comments

Comment: But why? this code is fine, problem in javascript code which contains files

Comment: Because I want to see your aspx design code to help you

Comment: aspx code, I already posted in my question. It's urgent please help me out of this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143274/discussion-between-jayakrishnan-gounder-and-nitika-chopra).